# Trying to parse user input. The input of 6 numbers must fall fall within the range of 1 to 46. If not, the user is returned to the input window

Tags: python

Need to check if user_input has any number that is not in numlist (range from 1 to 46)

```
user_input = []
numlist = list(range(1, 46))
while True:
    user_input = (list(int(num) for num in input("Enter the 6 numbers separated by space ").strip().split()))[:6]

    if not set(user_input).intersection(numlist):
        print("Number not in range")

    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Thanks all good - '.difference' did the job, but I changed  'else: continue' to 'else: break' to carry on processing 'user_input'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use difference function instead of intersection. `set(user_input).difference(numlist)` will return the set of numbers that are in `user_input` but not in `numlist`.

```
user_input = []
numlist = list(range(1, 46))
while True:
    user_input = (list(int(num) for num in input("Enter the 6 numbers separated by space ").strip().split()))[:6]

    if set(user_input).difference(numlist):
        print("Number not in range")

    else:
        continue
```